# Is there value in using a wp_nonce for POST requests?

Tags: security, nonce

All of the examples I see using `wp_create_nonce` are in the context of a GET request.  You embed a nonce in URLs to ensure malicious links or scripts can't trick a user into, say, deleting a post.

However, I'm creating a JSON API that only allows POST requests for persistent changes.  I've been racking my brain trying to figure out how a `wp_nonce` would improve security, and I'm coming up empty.

Assuming I enforce POST requests and check permissions appropriately with `current_user_can`, is there any reason to use a `wp_nonce` in this API?

Comment: "nonce" is usefull too with POST request. without this, a malicious website can force a user to do an action that the current connected user don't want. it just needs a form with a action on your website

Comment: @mmm Well, that was obvious and I feel really dumb now.  If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.